# Find Best Fit Equation From 4 Data Points

Tags: polynomials, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I have thousands of rows which each contain 4 different data values.

Data example:

> A = 799,  B = 190.68,  C = 131.74,  Y = 48.65

> A = 1209,  B = 9.67,  C = 9.67,  Y = 311.36

> A = 932,  B = 212.23,  C = 144.39,  Y = 136.22

I am looking for a method to find an equation that will best fit all of the data. So, then, when new A, B ,C values are given, I can use this equation to calculate the corresponding Y value.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:ordinary-differential-equations]?

Comment: Your question is particularly puzzling. You are asking a "best fit to get $Y$", though you know $Y$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, all of the data points are known. I am looking for a method to find the equation that will best fit the data as a whole so then a new A,B,C data set could be given and it would use this equation to predict Y based on the data it had previously.

Comment: Make some effort to restate your question correctly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. I changed the question so it is more clear.

Comment: Can you show us a plot of the curves of $A,B,C,D$ ?

Comment: One way to think of this that might be helpful ... Your (A,B,C) values can be regarded as points in 3D space, and you know the value of Y at each of these points. Now you want to construct a function that gives you a Y value at any point in space. Look up the term “scattered data interpolation”.

Comment: A good place to start might be this paper:  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.2949&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s call your given data points $P_i = (A_i, B_i, C_i)$ and let $Y_i$ denote the known function value at the point $P_i$.

You want to find a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(P_i) = Y_i$ for all $i$.

The easiest algorithm is the “closest point” one. Given a point $P$, you find the closest known point $P_k$ and then you just set $f(P) = Y_k$.

This function $f$ is not continuous, but you didn’t say that was necessary.

If you want a continuous (smooth) function, you’ll have to learn about multi-dimensional interpolation/approximation. You can start with the Alfeld paper I cited in the comment above.